# FB.login defaults to "only me" visibility, which means Facepile plugin doesn't work

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facepile

I do an FB.login with the scope being 'public_profile,email,user_friends'.

```
function fb_login() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }, {scope: 'public_profile,email,user_friends'});  
}

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
        cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
        version    : 'v2.1' // use version 2.1
   });
}
```

Also on the page I have a Facepile plugin.

```
<div class="fb-facepile" data-app-id="xxxxxxxxxxx" data-width="400" data-max-rows="1" data-colorscheme="light" data-size="large" data-show-count="true"></div>
```

The user can connect just fine.  However, the user cannot see their friends in the Facepile if those friends have also connected.  If a user logs into Facebook and goes to App Settings, the app is listed there, but the visibility is set to "Only Me".  If they manually change the visibility of the app to "Friends", only then can the user's friends see the person in the Facepile.

How do I configure the app or the login process to set the visibility to "Friends" so the user does not have to do this manually?

Comment: I'm having the same problem.. I think I know what the problem is.. I'll try it and let you know ASAP.

Comment: [facepile was abandoned](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/facepile/)